# Opposite of "In response to"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for the "outward" name for a relationship between two items. One is a request item, the other is the item created in response.

Other examples of are:

Name - Outward Name - Inward Name
Depend - "is required for" - "depends on"
Duplicate - "is duplicated by" - "duplicates"
Subtask - "parent for" - "subtask of"

The one I'm looking for would be:
Response - "????" - "response to"

Looking for something a little better than "Request" or "Inquiry".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *answered by* (for a definitive response)
- *addressed by* (for a less definitive response)
- *responded to by* (awkward, but probably the least ambiguous option)

Comment: I think "addressed by" fits the system quite well. I'm surprised I didn't think of it. Thank you.